# Concatenating/merging files vertically in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, time-series, numpy-ndarray

I can concatenate all the files in a directory with NumPy vertical stack. But it takes a long time compared to pandas (~30 seconds to merge while pandas consume only ~3 seconds to merge)

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
files = sorted(glob('ILU-545*.txt'))
print(files)
    array = np.loadtxt(files[0], delimiter='\t')
    for file in files[1:]:
         array = np.vstack((array, np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t')))
```

`array.shape=(2000000,16)` # This is OK but takes more time compared to pandas
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgTHp.jpg)
In pandas, I can call all the files in the directory but after concatenating the `data.shape` is different than `array.shape`

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
files = sorted(glob('ILU-545*.txt'))
print(files)
data = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t') for file in files))
data.head()
data.shape
```

Can anyone help me to fix the shape of the data by using pandas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Here is a blended way to stack vertically the files and finally the output is numpy array. It is
import os
import time
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path = "C:/Users/sys/PycharmProjects/test1"
start = time.time()

```
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "ILU-545*.txt"))
np_array_list = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, sep='\t',  index_col=None, header=None)
    np_array_list.append(df.values)
comb_np_array = np.vstack(np_array_list) # Array
BIG_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array) # Dataframe
print("Big Frame shape is: ", array.shape)
end = time.time()
print("Time Required (in sec) :", end - start)
```

In this way the `Big Frame shape is:  (57950000, 16)` and `Time Required (in sec): 90.41600012779236`.
with `np.vstack` (except pandas) it takes more time: `Time Required (in sec) : 1598.8368678092957` (18 times slower!!) for the same shape of the array`:  (57950000, 16)`. Welcome to the faster approach to merge files of the same type of integer data.

Comment: 'np_array_list.append(df.values)' gives me error message "KeyError(key)
KeyError: (slice(0, 50000, None), slice(None, None, None))" how can I fix it?

Comment: 'comb_np_array = np.vstack(np_array_list)' # This is an 'Array', for scientific computation we need array while 'BIG_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)' is a data frame sometimes creates problem.